# Named, Throwing Providers of Injected Objects

Tags: java, guice

I've been using guice casually for a while now, but not enough to figure out how to accomplish what I want in this case. It seems like I want some combination of `AssistedInject`, `Throwing Providers`, and `Multibindings`, but I'm not sure how to bring it all together. This is boiled-down code that doesn't quite work. It needs to be Guicier!

```
public class Utilities {
    public static String expensiveLookup(String key) throws IOException {...}
}

public class Helper {
    @Inject private InjectedClass injectedValue;

    public Helper(String value1, String value2, String value3) {...}
}

public class Workhorse {

    // This map isn't very guicy. I'd prefer named bindings, or a multibinding
    private static Map<String, Helper> helpers = new HashMap();

    public static void register(String name, Helper helper) {
        helpers.put(name, helper);
    }

    ////////

    @Inject lots of things

    public void doHardWork(String helperName) {
        Helper helper = helpers.get(helperName);
        // do something hard
    }
}

class UserModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {

        // Helpers are created with `new`, so they don't get `injectedValue`
        Workhorse.register("cheap helper", new Helper("cheap value", ...));

        try {
            // This expensive lookup should be delay until needed
            String expensiveValue = Utilities.expensiveLookup("expensive key");
            Workhorse.register("expensive helper", new Helper(expensiveValue, ...));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // This exception should be handled in `doHardwork()`
        }
    }
}
```

I can figure out how to solve any 2 of the problems at once, but not all 4:

- `Helper`s need to be created with Guice, not `new`
- `expensiveLookup` should be delayed until needed
- The `IOException` should be caught and handled by `doHardWork`
- The `helpers` map should probably be replaced with named bindings or a multibinding. This is not a hard requirement for me, but it seems right.

Can anyone offer some hints?

Comment: What are value2 and value3 in the helper constructor? are those also values that you lookup via key? or are they arbitrary at runtime?

Comment: Those are also specified in `UserModule`, but are just strings. No lookup needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally worked to a solution. I'm definitely not happy with it, because it requires about double the code and is difficult to understand, but it works. I sincerely hope there is an easier way.

```
public class Utilities {
    public static String expensiveLookup(String key) throws IOException {...}
}

public class Helper {
    private InjectedClass injectedValue;

    @Inject
    public Helper(
        @Assisted("value1") String value1, 
        @Assisted("value2") String value2, 
        @Assisted("value3") String value3,
        InjectedClass injectedValue) {

        this.injectedValue = injectedValue;
        ...
    }

    public static <T extends Provider> void installProvider(
        Binder binder, String name, Class<T> providerClass) {

        ThrowingProviderBinder.create(binder)
            .bind(ProviderInterface.class, Helper.class)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
            .to(providerClass)
            .in(Singleton.class);
    }

    abstract public static Provider implements ProviderInterface {
        @Inject private Factory factory;

        protected Helper expensiveBuild(
            String expensiveKey, 
            String value2, 
            String value3) throws IOException {

            String expensiveValue = Utilities.expensiveLookup(expensiveKey);
            return cheapBuild(expensiveValue, value2, value3);
        }

        protected Helper cheapBuild(String value1, String value2, String value3) {
            return Factory.create(value1, value2, value3);
        }
    }

    interface ProviderInterface extends CheckedProvider<Helper> {
        public Helper get() throws IOException;
    }

    interface Factory {
        Helper create(
            @Assisted("value1") String value1, 
            @Assisted("value2") String value2, 
            @Assisted("value3") String value3);
    }
}

class HelperModule exends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
            .implement(Helper.class, Helper.class)
            .build(Helper.Factory.class));
    }
}

public class Workhorse {
    @Inject lots of things
    @Inject private Injector injector;

    public void doHardWork(String helperName) {
        Key key = Key.get(Helper.ProviderInterface.class, Names.named(helperName));
        try {
            Helper helper = injector.getInstance(key).get(helperName);
            // do something hard
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

class UserModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        Helper.installProvider(binder(), "cheap helper", CheapProvider.class);
        Helper.installProvider(binder(), "expensive helper", ExpensiveProvider.class);
    }

    private static class CheapProvider extends Provider {
        public Helper get() {
            return cheapBuild("cheap value", ...);
        }
    }

    private static class ExpensiveProvider extends Provider {
        public Helper get() throws IOException {
            return expensiveBuild("expensive key", ...);
        }
    }
}
```

I would love it if anyone has a better answer!